# Create several mapbox-gl maps that show different markers using single map instance

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a page with several maps which show the same location with the same zoom/pitch (viewport is the same). The difference is that maps has markers in different locations and there are programmatically added layers (circles) additionally (viewport is the same).

It seems that all maps load the same tiles. Is there any options to configure mapbox-gl tiles caching to speed up maps loading?

Can i generate image and show it as base layer to all maps instances on the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't yet implemented in Mapbox GL JS, it's ticketed at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/2951